# Boundary and closure of a measure zero set is not measure zero?

Tags: measure-theory

> In $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $E$ has measure zero. Prove that $\bar{E}$ and $\partial E$ need not have measure zero.

I think I have a poor understanding of this. I know that $\bar{E} = int E \cup \partial E$

I am thinking that $E$ must be an open set. Because if $E$ were closed, then we get $\partial E\subset E$ and this implies $\partial E$ must have measure $0$. But now I have strayed away from the problem completely.

Should I start with a cover on $\partial E$ and deduce that the total volume over the cover is not necessarily less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: If $E$ is a finite set, then $E$ has measure zero and $\partial E=\bar{E}=E$...

Comment: How do we know $E$ is finite?

Comment: Branden's point is that the assertion to be proved is misstated. It should say that the closure and boundary *might* not have measure 0, because in some cases they do have measure 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that $E$ shouldn't be closed, but it doesn't follow that it should be open. The only open set of measure 0 is the empty set.  You could take $E$ to be the set of rational numbers (in $\mathbb R$).

Comment: Why can we take $E = \mathbb{Q}$? What if $\mathbb{Q} \subset E$?

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ has measure 0 because it's countable, and its closure and boundary are both $\mathbb R$, which does not have measure 0.

Comment: But how do you know $E$ is the rationals?

Comment: You are allowed to pick what $E$ is.

Comment: I don't know that $E$ is the rationals; I'm giving one example. See Brandon's and my comments on the question on the question for why one couldn't possibly prove the claim for arbitrary $E$.

Comment: $E$ is just given to be *some set* with measure zero, and you're being asked to find some $E$ that proves that it is possible for $E$ to be measure zero without its closure and boundary being measure zero. The rational points are measure zero in $\mathbb{R}$ but their boundary and closure have large measure, so they are an exmaple of such an $E$.

Comment: Okay, I completely misunderstood the problem then. So my idea about being closed sets answers another question then?

Comment: In fact, it did say "does not" until it was edited 7 minutes ago.  That's why I wrote that it's misstated.

Comment: Got it. I deleted my comment anyway since sidht deleted the comment it was a response to.

Comment: @sidht yes, your thought proves that a closed set of measure zero necessarily has measure zero boundary.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, you mentioned that no other nonemepty open sets could have measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it because that if I take $S = \{ (a - \epsilon/2, b + \epsilon/2) \}$ as an cover for $(a,b)$, then we have $V(S) = b - a + \epsilon < \epsilon$? I used the Lesbegue measure here.

Comment: Any nonempty open set $U$ includes a non-degenerate open interval $(a,b)$, and that has Lebesgue measure $b-a$.  So $U$ has Lebesgue measure at least $b-a$, and therefore in particular not zero.

Comment: So I am right…? Why does the Lebsegue measure here proves that no other measures can yield measure zero?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\Bbb Q$. The boundary and the closure of $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb R$.